# How does Google Directions API determine which route to return when alternatives attribute is set to false

Tags: google-maps, directions, google-directions-api

I am curious to know based on what parameter does the Directions API return the optimal route when making a request such as: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?alternatives=true&destination=47.3406139%2C8.5311766&language=en&mode=driving&origin=47.3903283%2C8.4911987&key=API_KEY .
When the attribute `alternatives=true` is added to the request, the API returns 3 possible routes. When the `alternatives` attribute is not specified, the API returns 1 response. How does it choose it?

Does it choose the shortest route, the fastest route or something in between ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this can be found when we look at what [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#optional-parameters) says on the `traffic_model` parameter, which defaults to `best_guess`.

> `best_guess` (default) indicates that the returned `duration_in_traffic`
>   should be the best estimate of travel time given what is known about
>   both historical traffic conditions and live traffic.
>
> The default value of `best_guess` will give the most useful predictions
>   for the vast majority of use cases. It is possible the `best_guess`
>   travel time prediction may be shorter than `optimistic`, or
>   alternatively, longer than `pessimistic`, due to the way the `best_guess`
>   prediction model integrates live traffic information.

Hope this helps!